# PDF Plugin Phonegap - Assert Error

Tags: ios, pdf, cordova, pdfviewer

So I am running the PDF Plugin from [here](http://randymcmillan.github.io/PDFViewer/) and after following the directions and adding it to my project everything seems to work fine, I get the screenshot below to open, but then when I tap on the "Click to open CordovaBot.pdf!" I get this error on my console and the screen freezes:

```
2013-08-16 13:55:10.984 [788:907] CordovaBot.pdf
Assertion failed: (filename != nil), function +[ReaderDocument archiveFilePath:], file /Users/.../phonegap-3.0.0/lib/ios/CordovaLib/ReaderDocument.m, line 118.
```

*Also to note I changed the format of the exec to the correct one, so this shouldn't be the issue.

[image]

Comment: why you should use plugin You can directly open PDf with inAppBrowse

Comment: I wanted to use this so I could call a separate window from within the app to be displayed in a smaller size in front of the app, from what I was under the impression that InAppBrowse could not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agh got it, had the add the file directly to the project folder main directory, HelloWorldProject/CordovaBot.pdf